# Terraform - Dynamic Inline Block using List Variable & Conditional

Tags: conditional-statements, terraform

Ooookay... This one is driving me insane. I've worked with AWS CloudFormation for a while now, and I've recently been tasked with 'converting' (or adapting) something I've created into a Terraform variant, ultimately to do the same thing (reasons).

For the most part, I'm getting along okay. But... I've come to my AWS_Instance section, which I was dreading in advance due to what I've learned about Terraform, and I'm completely and utterly stuck. I feel like I'm close, but I just cannot get it to work entirely, and so regarding the below; Thank you in advance for any help and suggestions!

**The issue**: I have an AWS instance to create - Depending on the users request, it will have X EBS storage devices attached to it. Either 2, 4, or none (let's say). In AWS CF, I simply do a condition via an IF statement; IF 2 then create A and B; ELIF 4 then create A, B, C and D, ELSE do nothing. Simple. In Terraform, I'm finding it VERY difficult to do that same simplicity. What I have so far is the following:

```
variable "test_list" {
  type = list
  default = [ "b", "c" ]
}

resource "aws_instance" "tf_instance" {
  #...#
  dynamic "ebs_block_device" {
    for_each = var.test_list
    content {
      device_name = "/dev/sd${ebs_block_device.value}"
      delete_on_termination = "true"
      volume_size = "2000"
      volume_type = "st1"
      encrypted = "${local.Instance_Encryption}"
    }
  }
}
```

This does create an instance with 2 attached disks (b and c) which is a step in the right direction, but the problem is that I cannot find a way to add in a conditional into that FOR_EACH step. I want to be able to have it create those 2 OR do nothing. I tried the following, but it errors out:

```
for_each = local.Single-Node ? [ var.test_list_2 ] : [ null ]
```

Potentially I'm just using it incorrectly (only been using Terraform for a few days, so some of my understanding is wrong for sure). Any help with this is highly appreciated, as I feel what I'm trying to do is a very basic thing [if this else do nothing] but I've scoured the internet to no avail!

Comment: You did not display your error message, but if I had to guess what went wrong, it is probably because you did a `list(null)` type. You probably actually wanted an empty list i.e. `[]` instead. If not, then please share your error message and other relevant information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Focusing on your framing of the problem as making a decision based on a number, I think I'd approach this by making a lookup table for each valid number, like this:

```
variable "block_device_count" {
  type = number
}

locals {
  block_device_letters_by_count = {
    2 = ["a", "b"]
    4 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
  }
  block_device_letters = try(local.block_device_letters_by_count[var.block_device_count], [])
}
```

This is using a map lookup to achieve a similar result to your previous IF, ELSEIF, ELSE approach. The [`try`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/try.html) here is acting as the "ELSE do nothing" part: if there's no element in the map matching `var.block_device_count` then it'll use an empty list as a fallback result.

Now `local.block_device_letters` is of a suitable shape to use with a `dynamic` block, so we can use it in a similar way as you showed in your example:

```
resource "aws_instance" "tf_instance" {
  #...#
  dynamic "ebs_block_device" {
    for_each = local.block_device_letters
    content {
      device_name = "/dev/sd${ebs_block_device.value}"
      delete_on_termination = "true"
      volume_size = "2000"
      volume_type = "st1"
      encrypted = "${local.Instance_Encryption}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Martin Atkins, you legend of a man, this is the second time you have saved me with one annoying headache of a problem. Thank you, good sir!